# How to exclude MVC Razor view from code coverage?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, code-coverage, visual-studio-test-runner

I want to exclude MVC views—i.e., `cshtml` files, which have C# code—from code the coverage report in ADO.

What I have tried is:

1. Adding the `[ExcludeFromCodeCoverage]` attribute to the `cshtml`.
2. Adding exclusion for the `*.Views` assembly in the `runsettings` file:

   ```xml
   <ModulePath>.*Views.*</ ModulePath>
   ```

Neither worked. Is there any way of achieving this?

Answer (score 3):

Once I was able to get the `runsettings` file recognized (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/configure-unit-tests-by-using-a-dot-runsettings-file?msclkid=14b6671abb6811ec9283acde13b7ff4e&view=vs-2022#specify-a-run-settings-file-in-the-ide), I was able to use this to exclude views that were being pre-compiled:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RunSettings>
  <DataCollectionRunSettings>
    <DataCollectors>
      <DataCollector friendlyName="Code Coverage" uri="datacollector://Microsoft/CodeCoverage/2.0" assemblyQualifiedName="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Coverage.DynamicCoverageDataCollector, Microsoft.VisualStudio.TraceCollector, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a">
        <Configuration>
          <CodeCoverage>

            <ModulePaths>
              <Include>
                <!-- Make sure we include all the project source -->
                <ModulePath>.*your.project.library.name.dll</ModulePath>
                <ModulePath>.*your.project.name.dll</ModulePath>
              </Include>
            </ModulePaths>

            <Sources>
              <Exclude>
                <Source>.*cshtml.*</Source> <!-- Ignore the pre-compiled views for code coverage -->
              </Exclude>
            </Sources>

            <!-- We recommend you do not change the following values: -->
            <UseVerifiableInstrumentation>True</UseVerifiableInstrumentation>
            <AllowLowIntegrityProcesses>True</AllowLowIntegrityProcesses>
            <CollectFromChildProcesses>True</CollectFromChildProcesses>
            <CollectAspDotNet>False</CollectAspDotNet>

          </CodeCoverage>
        </Configuration>
      </DataCollector>
    </DataCollectors>
  </DataCollectionRunSettings>
</RunSettings>
```

Comment: To exclude only the pages themselves and not the backing models, change the line to `<Source>.*cshtml$</Source>`.